# PHPUnit selenium doesn't support sendKeys?

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I was writing test with `sendKeys` command at Selenium IDE that was fine. But when I was change to PHPUnit Selenium I got an error that was `Method sendKeys not defined`, so I want to know is `PHPUnit-Selenium` doesn't support or I need to add  a method? If the answer is I need to add `senKeys` method if so let's me know how to add `senKeys` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I couldn't figure this one out either for a while... the trick is that it's not called sendKeys and you don't use {ENTER} in PHPUnit with Selenium. These are not the functions you are looking for!

Instead, click on the element you wish to type into and then use the keys function like so:

```
$this->byXpath('//*[@id="theOneToTypeIn"]')->click();
$this->keys('some keys to type'.Keys::ENTER);
```

Make sure that at the top of your page you include the Keys class as well:

```
use PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Keys as Keys;
```

The supported keys can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/element/:id/value

I read that the SendKeys are supported the same was as in the JSON wire frame so I would imagine that the constants are the same names as they are in that link... but then I also imagined that all the function names would be the same and here we are.