# PHP: Sending left, right, up and down arrow keys in selenium tests

Tags: php, selenium, arrow-keys

I am writing selenium browser tests in php. To test dropdown and HTML5 date inputs, I want to send the arrow keys to the browser, something like:

```
$dateInput->sendKeys(ARROW_LEFT);
```

I found quite some examples in Java, but none for PHP.
I tried to find the ASCII code of these keys to send them with `chr` (ascii-number), but the arrow keys actually are not in the 128 `ascii` signs.

So, can anyone hint me in the right direction how to send the arrow keys in PHP?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559705/phpunit-selenium-doesnt-support-sendkeys

Comment: This seems to be what I was lookign for, will test:
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/master/lib/WebDriverKeys.php